# SUMPRODUCT with 3 Criteria, index match by 1 Row & 2 Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

Please help me..

I have a table that I want to SUM with condition of multiple criteria by 1 row & 2 column.

The Formula:
[image: The Formula]

Column that should be result of SUM:
[image: column that should be SUM]

expected result:
[image: expected result]

I Have tried some formula but it just sum of first column, i need to sum of all numbers of table "I10:N47".

here my code below:

```
=IFNA(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$H$10:$H$47=Sheet2!$B6)*(INDEX(Sheet1!$I$10:$N$47,,MATCH(Sheet2!$C$2,Sheet1!$I$5:$N$5,0))):(INDEX(Sheet1!$I$10:$N$47,,MATCH(Sheet2!$C$3,Sheet1!$I$6:$N$6,0)))),0)
```

thanks for the support..

Comment: what is the content of `$A$106` , `PDG!$B106` and `PDG!$A$3` ?

Comment: I have edited for clear table Sir @p._phidot_ , please the advise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example you may be able to adjust to your ranges:

[image]

Formual in `G4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6=G1)*((B1:D1=G2)+(B1:D1=G3))*(B2:D6))
```

Or applying some `SUMIFS` logic:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G1,A:A,0)):INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G1,A:A,0)),B1:D1,G2:G3))
```

---

***<sub>Edit1:</sub>***

As per your comment, there can be same headers:

[image]

Formula in `H4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6=H1)*((B1:E1=H2)+(B1:E1=H3))*(B2:E6))
```

---

***<sub>Edit2:</sub>***

After your last comment I see you have several lines of headers that need to match up, try to adjust the below:

[image]

Formula in `G4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A7=H1)*(B1:E1=H2)*(B2:E2=H3)*(B3:E7))
```

Comment: I Have edited the Table.. in that example, there is 2 header and appear more than one Sir @JvdV, please the advise..thank you

Comment: Im not understanding what would be wrong with the first formula in that case @LuthfiTryWando.

Comment: i mean, in my case, my table array has 2 column header row 5 & row 6 (Sheet2) that should be index & match with "Brand" ..